# getting localised text of english version

Tags: ubuntu, glib

I have a file name say Index.xml which is in english version,

and there are same copy of files in other languages. how can glib know that a Index-fr.xml

of french version has to be opened when system has been localized to french.

Comment: What is the relevance of glib here?

Comment: @Steve:glib will know the language where the system has been set, if i am right. if not what can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pickup the locale setting via [`setlocale()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setlocale) such as "`en_US.UTF-8`".